# Groupby mean of int group variable and float values return nothing

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I have the following two columns in my dataframe

```
      hs92_product_id  Dummy_Weight
2578           854470        0.0000
2579           854470        0.0000
2580           854470        0.0000
2581           111111        0.5000
2582           111111        0.1000
2583           111111        0.0000
2584           111111        0.0000
2585           222222        0.2500
2586           222222        0.2500
2587           222222        0.0000
```

where Dummy_Weight is float64 and  hs92_product_id is int64

when I try to get the mean by product group:

> df['Risk Weighted'] =
>   df.groupby('hs92_product_id')['Dummy_Weight'].mean()

it returns a column of missing values, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for Series filled by aggregated values with same size like original DataFrame:

```
df['Risk Weighted'] = df.groupby('hs92_product_id')['Dummy_Weight'].transform('mean')
print (df)
      hs92_product_id  Dummy_Weight  Risk Weighted
2578           854470          0.00       0.000000
2579           854470          0.00       0.000000
2580           854470          0.00       0.000000
2581           111111          0.50       0.150000
2582           111111          0.10       0.150000
2583           111111          0.00       0.150000
2584           111111          0.00       0.150000
2585           222222          0.25       0.166667
2586           222222          0.25       0.166667
2587           222222          0.00       0.166667
```

---

> it returns a column of missing values, why?

If check output of `groupby` + `mean` get:

```
print (df.groupby('hs92_product_id')['Dummy_Weight'].mean())
hs92_product_id
111111    0.150000
222222    0.166667
854470    0.000000
Name: Dummy_Weight, dtype: float64
```

Here `index` is created by unique values of `hs92_product_id` with `mean`. After assign to new column pandas try align indices and if no match, filled missing values.

Verify in changed data sample:

```
print (df)
        hs92_product_id  Dummy_Weight
2578             854470          0.00
111111           854470          0.00 <- changed index value
2580             854470          0.00
2581             111111          0.50
2582             111111          0.10
2583             111111          0.00
2584             111111          0.00
2585             222222          0.25
2586             222222          0.25
2587             222222          0.00

print (df.groupby('hs92_product_id')['Dummy_Weight'].mean())
111111    0.150000 <- same index value exist in original df
222222    0.166667
854470    0.000000
Name: Dummy_Weight, dtype: float64

df['Risk Weighted'] = df.groupby('hs92_product_id')['Dummy_Weight'].mean()
print (df)
        hs92_product_id  Dummy_Weight  Risk Weighted
2578             854470          0.00            NaN
111111           854470          0.00           0.15 <- data if indexes are aligned
2580             854470          0.00            NaN
2581             111111          0.50            NaN
2582             111111          0.10            NaN
2583             111111          0.00            NaN
2584             111111          0.00            NaN
2585             222222          0.25            NaN
2586             222222          0.25            NaN
2587             222222          0.00            NaN
```